# Element wise batch matrix multiplication of a row with every other row in matrix, in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

I have two matrices of sizes `(30, 24, 512)` respectively where `30` is the batch size. Let us call them `A` and `B`.

Now what I need to do is this:

For every batch in `A`, I want to compute element-wise batch matrix multiplication of each row in a single batch of `A` with each row in a single batch of `B` and sum them.
In other words, for every batch, I have a (24, 512) matrix on left-hand side (`A`) and on right-hand side (`B`). Now for each row `(1 * 512)` in `A`, I want to compute element-wise matrix multiplication of that row with each of the `(24 * 512)` rows in B, one by one, and sum them.
This operation would thus result in a `(1 * 512)` sized vector.
Done for each row in A, it would result in a `(24 * 512)` sized matrix and then, done for each batch it would result in `(30, 24, 512)` sized matrix, which is the preferred dimension of my output.

How do I go about doing this?
I do not want to use for loops, since that would be inefficient. I also do not want to use `repeat` method for the same reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer to my own question. Instead of computing the element-wise product of each row and then wanting to compute the sum, I summed the rows and then took the element-wise product, which made the problem (and the solution) much simpler.

```
import torch

a = torch.randn(30, 24, 512)
b = torch.randn(30, 24, 512)

# Step 1: Summing b along dimension 1 and unsqueezing
# Dimension of b_sum is 30*1*512
b_sum = torch.sum(b, dim=1).unsqueeze(1)

# Step 2: Element-wise product 
result = a * b_sum
```

Comment: Please mark your answer with green tick as solved for future readers, thanks for participating! You can read about it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: @SzymonMaszke oh yes I did try to earlier, but I get an error saying I can only accept my answer tomorrow.

Comment: @remorax Are you tomorrow's yet?